# How to reverse order a vector?

Tags: r, sorting, vector, reverse

Suppose I have a vector `v`, how do I get its reverse, i.e. last element first?

The first thing that comes to me is `v[length(v):1]`, but it returns NA when `v` is `numeric(0)`, while user normally expect sorting nothing returns nothing, not sorting nothing returns the unavailable thing - it does make a big difference in my case.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You are almost there; `rev` does what you need:

```
rev(1:3)
# [1] 3 2 1
rev(numeric(0))
# numeric(0)
```

Here's why:

```
rev.default
# function (x) 
# if (length(x)) x[length(x):1L] else x
# <bytecode: 0x0b5c6184>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

In the case of `numeric(0)`, `length(x)` returns 0. As `if` requires a logical condition, it coerces `length(x)` to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. It happens that `as.logical(x)` is `FALSE` when `x` is 0 and `TRUE` for any other number.

Thus, `if (length(x))` tests precisely what you want - whether `x` is of length zero. If it isn't, `length(x):1L` has a desirable effect, and otherwise there is no need to reverse anything, as @floder has explained in the comment.

Comment: +1 - just to explain what is happening with the OP in the case where `v <- c()`: `length(v):1` is `0:1`. The `[` operator ignores the `0` and returns `v[1]`, i.e. `NA`. If it were not for `rev`, something robust and along the lines of the OP would have been `v[seq(to = 1, by = -1, length.out = length(v))]`.

Answer (score 0):

Re: flodel's comment, if you want to try recreating `rev()` yourself, you could do something like:

```
rev2 <- function(v) if (length(v) > 0) v[length(v):1] else v
```

And in fact, this is actually what `rev()` is - see the source code [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/base/R/rev.R).