# reverse colors in colorNumeric()

Tags: r, leaflet, choropleth

I am trying to reverse the colors of a choropleth map. I am using the leaflet package and the `colorNumeric()` function, here is the code that generates the palette function:

```
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlGnBu", domain = foo$p)
```

I would like to do something like that:

```
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlGnBu", domain = foo$p, trans='reverse')
```

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Do `pal[length(pal):1]` works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse order a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933441/how-to-reverse-order-a-vector)

Comment: I do not think that it is clear for everyone that a color palette is a vector. Hence, I wouldn't call it a duplicate of the above mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without an example I cannot tell if it works with your code but try this:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
palette <- brewer.pal(5, "YlGnBu")
previewColors(colorNumeric(palette = palette, domain = 1:5), values = 1:5)
```

[image]

And the reverse:

```
palette_rev <- rev(brewer.pal(5, "YlGnBu"))
previewColors(colorNumeric(palette = palette_rev ,domain = 1:5), values = 1:5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

At least in leaflet 1.1.0+ colorNumeric has an optional "reverse" argument, so you can just do:

```
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlGnBu", domain = foo$p, reverse = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Alex here's an example using `rev` with some actual data:

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(RColorBrewer)

clrs <- rev(brewer.pal(9, "YlGnBu"))

pal <- colorNumeric(palette = clrs, domain = poppendorf[[5]][])

m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() 

m %>% 
  addRasterImage(x = poppendorf[[5]], color = pal)
```

Comment: No offence intended! You must have provided your answer while I was still trying and typing my answer... I've edited mine to acknowledge yours.